Google Maps Custom Overlay does not cover whole map
I am working with Google Maps CustomOverlay, defined following onAdd function:
onAdd = () => {
    if (this.overlay && this.canvasRef.current) {
        const canvas = this.canvasRef.current;
        const mapDiv = this.props.map.getDiv(); // Get the map container element

        canvas.style.position = "absolute"; // Ensure absolute positioning
        canvas.width = mapDiv.offsetWidth; // Set width dynamically
        canvas.height = mapDiv.offsetHeight; // Set height dynamically
        canvas.style.pointerEvents = "none"; // Prevent interaction with canvas
        this.overlay?.getPanes()?.overlayLayer.appendChild(canvas);

        // Listen for map resize and update canvas size
        google.maps.event.addListener(this.props.map, "resize", () => {
        canvas.width = mapDiv.offsetWidth;
        canvas.height = mapDiv.offsetHeight;
        this.overlay?.draw(); // Redraw after resizing
        });
    }
};

The problem is that the canvas is rendered with the top-left corner in the middle of the map. Inspecting the google maps generated DOM, I see that the canvas parent has the following style:
z-index: 1;
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
width: 100%;
will-change: transform;
transform: translate(0px, 0px);


I searched on the web but did not find a solution. Any hint?
Notice, I use React Functional Components:
class CustomOverlay extends Component<CustomOverlayProps> {}
EDIT1:
Gif showing the problem:

I created a sandbox reproducing the problem.
EDIT2:
I wonder why people vote for closing because of Needs debugging details. There is a sandbox included...

Please provide a runnable snippet that allows to reproduce the issue.

I added a gif showing the problem and a sandbox.

Your sandbox doesn't work at all, nothing shows.

Maybe because you have to add your api key? I cannot share mine...
